# Nuxt 3 i18n fetch locales from an API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I came across an issue in my Nuxt 3 app where I wanted to use i18n. I did my fair amount of research, but I couldn't find any useful informations, hence here comes my question.
I'm using i18n in combination with Prismic CMS. Locales array comes from Prismic API, I fetch it via my composable `useLocales`. Inside `useLocales` I also set it to global state via `useState` and returns it.
After successful fetch, I want to populate i18n instance with it. That's the scenario.
However, fairly quickly I realised that it's not as obvious thing to do as I would think - none of my approaches worked so far.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Making fetch directly inside `defineNuxtConfig` and setting the payload as value of `locales` key - obviously this one won't work, since it's not possible to perform async operations there.

```js
// Inside defineNuxtConfig
i18n: {
    ...
    locales: await useLocales(),
    defaultLocale: "en-pl",
    ...
},
```

2. Making fetch in custom plugin and setting the payload as value of `locales` key of $i18n property. Interestingly, it updates `locales` (I can see it using `usei18n` composable), but doesn't affect routing system:

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async ({ $i18n }) => {
    const locales = await useLocales();
    $i18n.locales = locales;
});
```

3. Making fetch in custom plugin the same way, but rather creating new instance of i18n:

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async ({ vueApp }) => {
    const locales = await useLocales();
    const i18nInstance = createI18n({
        legacy: false,
        globalInjection: true,
        locale: "en-pl",
        locales: locales,
    });
    vueApp.use(i18nInstance);
});
```

In the docs and in community channels all I can see is the approach where locales data is hardcode - I can hardly find my use case on the web, which is kind of surprising for me, since it's super common.

I really hope someone can give me a hint how to set those locales correctly

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing and have tried the exact same ideas - no luck so far.

Comment: @uNki Unfortunately, at least not with a clean solution. At the end I've decided to keep the list of all locales in my frontend codebase in nuxt.config, without making a request to other app. It's acceptable in my project where list of locales doesn't change so often, however in more dynamic project it wouldn't be as useful I guess

Comment: I also gave up and use a super simple approach. I fetch the locales and pages config from the CMS in a small script and save the response as json files and reference those in the nuxt.config.ts - works :)

Answer (score 1):

in order to fetch locales messages from async method, you can use this approach that recommended by https://i18n.nuxtjs.org website:

First step: (set lazy: true)

```
i18n: {
  locales: [
    {
      code: 'en',
      file: 'en-US.js'
    },
    {
      code: 'es',
      file: 'es-ES.js'
    },
    {
      code: 'fr',
      file: 'fr-FR.js'
    }
  ],
  lazy: true,
  langDir: 'lang/',
  defaultLocale: 'en'
}
```

Then resolve fetched locales from async method:

```
export default async (context, locale) => {
  return await Promise.resolve({
    welcome: 'Welcome'
  })
}

// or

export default {
  welcome: 'Welcome'
}
```

Reffer to docs: [link](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/lazy-load-translations)

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my question - I'm not asking for translations, but rather the array of locales itself. As you can clearly see, in the example you posted locales are hardcoded, it's the translations that are fetched dynamically